# how to have the correct cardinality of the relationship?

Tags: java, jpa

I've created a project with maven on netbeans. after defining the tables in mySql program i'm trying to generate the entity classes from database, using the Netbeans IDE.

The thing is that I have a table Cage and a table Animal and i wnat it to be a one to one relationship, but when i generate the entities the IDE put it as a one to many relationship (with the anotattions).

I think that my tables, in the database, are well created
What am i doing wrong? How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three cases where a `@OneToOne` would be used by a DB schema reverse engineering tool:

1. The associated entities share the same primary keys values
2. A foreign key is held by one of the entities and this FK column in the database has a  unique constraint in order to emulate one-to-one multiplicity
3. An association table is used to store the link between the 2 entities (a unique constraint has to be defined on each FK to ensure the one to one multiplicity).

If your tables do not have one of the aforementioned characteristics `@OneToMany` will be used.

Check out [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/jpatutorial-2-092215.html) tutorial for more details (that is where the three aforementioned cases are from)

Comment: Ty so much man... I had the foreign key, but didnt have it as unique in the database collumn.. can u elaborate a little bit further why is that needed? tks a lot

Comment: Your welcome! If the foreign key is not unique, then multiple rows in that table can have the same value, and therefore it would not be a one-to-one relationship. When you make the foreign key unique, you and tool know that no two rows can have the same value and therefore you have emulated a one to one relationship